# apache - cannot see pages in DocumentRoot, after setup a VirtualHost

Tags: apache, virtualhost

well, after setup a VirtualHost in httpd.conf , I'm not able to visit pages in DocumentRoot and all request are forwarded to the defined VirtualHost!

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/apache24/data"
<Directory "/usr/local/www/apache24/data">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks   
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.site     
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/apache24/data/sub_domain_site/ 
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /usr/local/www/apache24/data/sub_domain_site/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Please note that, the VirtualHost has a DNS entry and so could be accessible in internet with its name. However what I need to accomplish now is to access the pages stored in apache default DocumentRoot via server IP.

Answer (score 0):

I've add another VirtualHost block just after the current defined VirtualHost for my subdomain. and in the new one I've entered ServerName [IP-ADDRESS] , and also point it to apache default DocumentRoot. It worked just fine.

So I wonder if I did it in correct way ? is there any better way for doing this ?

Thanks,